# Alternating Switches ON/OFF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygtk, gtk3

So I want to have my small Python Gtk window have 2 switches. When one switch is ON, the other is turned OFF, and vice versa. I am not too sure how to control both switches. If anyone can lead me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class SwitcherWindow(Gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Alt Switch Demo")
    self.set_border_width(10)

    hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
    self.add(hbox)

    switch1 = Gtk.Switch()
    switch1.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_activated)
    switch1.set_active(True)
    hbox.pack_start(switch1, True, True, 0)

    switch2 = Gtk.Switch()
    switch2.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_activated)
    switch2.set_active(False)
    hbox.pack_start(switch2, True, True, 0)

    if switch1.get_active():
        switch2.set_active(False)
    else:
        switch2.set_active(True)

def on_switch_activated(self, switch, gparam):
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    sw1 = builder.get_object("switch1")
    sw2 = builder.get_object("switch2")
    if switch.get_active():
        state = "on"
        sw2.set_active(False)
    else:
        state = "off"
        print("Switch was turned", state)

win = SwitcherWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [bind the properties](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.bind_property) of both switches, inverted and sync'ed on creation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject 

class SwitcherWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Alt Switch Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.add(hbox)

        switch1 = Gtk.Switch()
        switch1.set_active(True)
        hbox.pack_start(switch1, True, True, 0)

        switch2 = Gtk.Switch()
        switch2.set_active(False)
        hbox.pack_start(switch2, True, True, 0)

        switch1.bind_property("active", switch2, "active", GObject.BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL | GObject.BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE |  GObject.BindingFlags.INVERT_BOOLEAN)   


win = SwitcherWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The solution resides on this line of code:

```
switch1.bind_property("active", switch2, "active", GObject.BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL | GObject.BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE |  GObject.BindingFlags.INVERT_BOOLEAN)
```

Here you [bind](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.bind_property) the `"active"` property of `switch1` and `switch2` with the [binding flags](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/flags.html#GObject.BindingFlags): [bidirectional](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/flags.html#GObject.BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL), [sync on create](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/flags.html#GObject.BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE) and [invert boolean](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/flags.html#GObject.BindingFlags.INVERT_BOOLEAN)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a similar logic to what I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class Switch:
    _State = False

    def __init__(self, StartingPosition=False):
        self._State = StartingPosition

    def SwitchON(self):
        self._State = True

    def SwitchOFF(self):
        self._State = False

    def Switch(self):
        self._State = not self._State

    def GetInfo(self):
        print(self._State)


class Switcher:
    def __init__(self, switchDependencyList=[]):
        self.SwitchDependencyList = switchDependencyList
        if len(self.SwitchDependencyList) == 0:
            return None
        if not len(self.SwitchDependencyList) % 2:
            return None

    def SwitchByIndex(self, Index):
        for i, switch in enumerate(self.SwitchDependencyList):
            if i == Index:
                switch.SwitchON()
            else:
                switch.SwitchOFF()

    def GetInfo(self):
        for switch in self.SwitchDependencyList:
            switch.GetInfo()


sw1 = Switch()
sw2 = Switch()
SwitcherModule = Switcher([sw1, sw2])
SwitcherModule.SwitchByIndex(1)
SwitcherModule.GetInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for anything as complex as the prelisted answers. gtk already has a radiobutton widget that does it all for you. Only thing is that when it is initialised you have no buttons set, so you have to pick one to set.

Comment: Hi Paul, the question specifically asks for GtkSwitch'es to be used. Binding two properties is nothing one could characterize as "complex", if you compare the question code with the solution one you would see that it has less code. I think that your answer could be a comment and IF it was a route to follow, then you could present a solution. Cheers

Comment: No it does not ask specifically for a GtkSwitch. It just asks for a switch. A GtkSwitch is given by example. The functionality the OP asks for is a radio button and for UX it is better to present a widget that visually demonstrates that functionality than widgets that don't. None of the answers above also tinker around on the ATK side of things. It is important to establish relationships between items for accessibility.

Comment: Hi again Paul, I think you are assuming too much without questioning @Mauricio Rivera. You could be right but your "answer" is not an answer it's a comment. If you want to present it as an answer then care to elaborate a real answer. That was just my intention. Good luck

Comment: The OP asked open endedly to be led in the right direction. Seriously. How is it not a "real" answer.